# Extract title from torrent name

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to create a mechanism that extracts proper titles and possibly other metadata from Torrent names for TV shows and other types. As you may be aware, Torrent names contain various crap such as dots and other irrelevant strings.

Specifically, I have data of some ten thousand correctly converted torrent names to proper title and more. I should use this "training set" somehow.

What ML method should I employ? I know there are regex-type solutions to this problem, but I would like to find a Machine Learning solution.

Comment: Imho the most direct option is to treat this as a machine translation problem.

Comment: Great, thank you @Erwan! I will read up on such a pipeline.